# Accessing private field of interface inside abstract test class

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have an abstract base test class and an interface. Inside the test class, a private field of type interface is declared.

```
abstract class FibonacciTest {
  *private FibonacciImplementation fibonacciImplementation;*

   public FibonacciImplementation getImplementation(){
       return this.fibonacciImplementation;
   }
   protected void setImplementation(FibonacciImplementation fibimplem){
       this.fibonacciImplementation = fibimplem;
   }
  abstract void createFibonacciImplementation();

  @BeforeEach
  void createImplementation(){
    createFibonacciImplementation();
  }

  @Test
  void invalidPosition(){
    assertEquals(new BigInteger("-2"),
      fibonacciImplementation.calculateFib(-2));
  }
```

The interface is:

```
public interface FibonacciImplementation {
  BigInteger calculateFib(int position);
}
```

The sub test classes for the base test class is something like this:

```
public class RecursiveFibonacciTest extends FibonacciTest{

  @BeforeEach
  void createFibonacciImplementation(){
    fibonacciImplementation = new RecursiveFibonacciImplementation();* error is here
  }
}
```

The recursivefibonacciImplentation is this:

```
public class RecursiveFibonacciImplementation implements FibonacciImplementation {

  @Override
  public BigInteger calculateFib(int position) {

    if(position < 0 )
      return new BigInteger("" + position);
    if(position == 1 || position == 0)
      return new BigInteger("1");

    return calculateFib(position-1).add(calculateFib(position-2));
  }
}
```

The problem I have is that when in the sub test class, the compiler complains that i am trying to access a private field. The `private FibonacciImplementation fibonacciImplementation;` field. How do i remove that error. How do I access `fibonacciImplementation`? The getter and setter does not seem to work.The compiler says `fibonacciImplementation has private access in FibonacciTest`.

Mind you, the requirement is that it has to be a private field.

Comment: Why exactly does it have to be `private`?

Comment: Mark `fibonacciImplementation` as protected, or provide a setter method.

Comment: Why you dont you initialize `fibonacciImplementation` in `FibonacciTest. createImplementation`? Like so `fibonacciImplementation = createFibonacciImplementation()`.

Comment: @PM it is the requirement of the assignment

Comment: @AndrewS where do I put the setter method? Inside the base class?

Comment: yes - the setter would go in the base class (as protected).

Comment: @AndrewS It still gives the same complaint

Comment: @tsolakp the compiler says it clashes with the initialization in the recursivetest class

Comment: From the comments I gather than in the answer there _must_ be a field and it _must_ be private, because these are the requirements of the assignment (a homework assignment, I guess). You might want to make all these constraints very clear in the question, since the correct answer depends on that. (Whether we should directly solve homework problems or not is another question, but this has been discussed elsewhere already).

Comment: @abl i have tried everything i can think of thats why i posted it here. I have seen many hw questions asked on this site

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a field at all? If instances of the implementing classes are not expensive to create, you can just get an instance only when you need it, no need to store it in a field.

```
abstract class FibonacciTest {

  abstract FibonacciImplementation createFibonacciImplementation();

  @Test
  void invalidPosition(){
    assertEquals(new BigInteger("-2"),
      createFibonacciImplementation().calculateFib(-2));
  }

}


public class RecursiveFibonacciTest extends FibonacciTest{

  @Override
  FibonacciImplementation createFibonacciImplementation(){
    return new RecursiveFibonacciImplementation();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`private` means it can only be accessed from within the same class. If you want a field only to be accessible by sub-classes, you'll want to mark it as `protected`.

Change this:

```
private FibonacciImplementation fibonacciImplementation;
```

To this:

```
protected FibonacciImplementation fibonacciImplementation;
```

In the `FibonacciTest` class.

Comment: I cant make it protected. The requirements of the assignment says i need to have it private